# Hair Particle not showing up in render

Tags: rendering, particles

I'm using the hair particles to make grass but for some reason, it's just not showing up.

What I made:
 [image]

What is rendered in the preview: 
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the full Properties for the hair particles.

Comment: Can you show your full particle settings ? Especially Render, Display and Cycles hairs settings. Also, make sur "Use hair" is checked in the render settings (under Geometry)

Comment: Okay, I added the full Properties panel for the Hair particles, P.s, I checked if the "Use Hair" is checked and it is.